# alert letters by name on pressing keyboard buttons without using a switch statement

Tags: javascript

Here i have a simple piece of code.I want it  to alert letters [A-Z] on pressing buttons on keyboard representing those letters.Till now it only alerting keyCodes.I know i can do that whit a switch statement.But it will be a large piece of switch statement. So my questions are:

1.Is there a way  i can alert every letters by their name on keypress without a switch statement?

2.Left,right,up,down arrow keys are not alerting their keycode numbers.Why is that so??How can i overcome this problem??

```
(function(){
    document.body.addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
            alert(e.keyCode);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the letters from their keyCode:

```
alert (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
```

To address the problems with the arrow-keys not showing their `keyCode`s (37 - 40):

```js
(function(){
    document.body.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
      // the keyCodes of the arrow keys, matched to an appropriate
      // unicode arrow symbol:
      var directionals = {
        '38' : 8593, // String.fromCharCode(38) => &
        '39' : 8594, // String.fromCharCode(39) => '
        '40' : 8595, // String.fromCharCode(40) => (
        '37' : 8592 // String.fromCharCode(37) => %
      },
          // if there is a falsey value from directionals object,
          // we use the e.keyCode unchanged; otherwise we substitute
          // e.keyCode for the above-supplied arrow-character:
          keyCodeToUse = !directionals[e.keyCode] ? e.keyCode : directionals[e.keyCode];
      // I don't like alerts; to access the console (in most browsers) press 'F12':
      console.log(String.fromCharCode(keyCodeToUse));
    });
})();
```

```css
html, body {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,180, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
}
```

The problem itself is that (for whatever reason) the arrow keys only return keyCodes on `keyup` and `keydown`, *not* on `keypress`. Further, the `String.fromCharCode()` using their key codes (as shown in the JavaScript, above) return characters that are not, in fact, arrows. So, we have to use alternate Unicode references (supplied above, in the JavaScript).

References:

- [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).

Comment: thanks for making things clear..:) .I have a question here?why there are two numbers to define a single key?i mean what is the relation and difference between '38' and '8593'?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) function for this:

```
String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
```